# Getting Stack Overflow Error on specific SQL pull in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, mvvm

My code keeps getting hung up on the 'using(SqlDataReader Reader = new cmd.ExecuteReader())' line throwing a StackOverflowException. I have not had this issue for any other SQL pulls from this same database, using the same general idea. I'm rather at a loss for what could be causing this issue, I've been trouble shooting it a fair bit by changing certain lines but it comes back to getting hung on that specific line.

```
public TeamRepository getTeamsinLeague(League L)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        Model.TeamRepository MTR = new TeamRepository();
        Model.Team T = new Team();
        if (L == null) { L = new League { Id = 1 }; }
        String queryString = "SELECT Id, City, Name, r, g, b, Fontr, Fontg, Fontb FROM dbo.Team WHERE Team.League = " + L.Id +";";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection_String))
        {

            conn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);

            using (SqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    T = new Team
                    {
                        Id = (int)Reader[0],
                        City = Reader[1].ToString(),
                        Name = Reader[2].ToString(),
                        MainRed = (int)Reader[3],
                        MainGreen = (int)Reader[4],
                        MainBlue = (int)Reader[5],
                        SecondaryRed = (int)Reader[6],
                        SecondaryGreen = (int)Reader[7],
                        SecondaryBlue = (int)Reader[8],
                    };
                    MTR.addTeam(T);
                }
            }

        }
        return MTR;
    }
```

Editing in the call of the getTeamsInLeague

```
//*****************************************
        //Variable Declarations
        //*****************************************

        public Model.TeamRepository _TeamRepository { get; set; }
        public Model.Team _SelectedTeam;
        public LeagueRepository _MLR { get; set; }
        private Model.League _L;
        public Model.League L { get { return _L; } set { _TeamRepository = sdm.getTeamsinLeague(L); L = value; } }
        SqlDataMap sdm = new SqlDataMap();
```

and the relevent XML

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding _MLR.LeagueArray}" SelectedItem="{Binding L}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Comment: In the model view under a binded variable: `public Model.League L { get { return _L; } set { _TeamRepository = sdm.getTeamsinLeague(L); L = value; } }` Will edit into first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `L` property is weirdly implemented. You cannot set a property in the setter of the same property itself. This will lead to a `StackoverflowException`.

Set the *field* instead of the property:

```
public Model.League L
{ 
    get { return _L; } 
    set { _L = value; _TeamRepository = sdm.getTeamsinLeague(_L); } 
}
```

And please following the [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

Comment: Shouldn't those be two separate 'L's as they are in two separate classes. getTeamsInLeague.L and EditTeamModelView.L  ...   and yes shame on me for poor variable naming, I will clean it up once I fix this

Comment: Did you try to remove `_TeamRepository = sdm.getTeamsinLeague(L);` from the setter?

Comment: Yes and runs clean. Tried to change the L in the class giving errors and now it is throwing MSB201 and MSB207 which is basically the same as overflow but somehow different. Honestly at a loss.

Comment: See my edit. You cannot set a property in the setter of the same property.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it, and I'll run through all the naming to ensure I'm following convention.